# remove path name in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

i would like remove actual path name at the top in react native

my code:

```js
import { View, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import FreshPage from './pages/FreshPage';
import { NativeRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-native";
import NotFound from './pages/NotFound';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NativeRouter initialEntries={["/"]}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path="/fresh" element={<FreshPage/>} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound/>} />
      </Routes>
    </NativeRouter>
  );
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('app', () => App);
```

my fresh page code:

```js
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-native";

export default function FreshPage() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>FreshPage</Text>
      <Button title={`retourner a l'accueil`} onPress={() => navigate("/")}></Button>
      <Button title={`page 404`} onPress={() => navigate("/404")}></Button>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  }
})
```

[actual path name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJxhX.png)

how to remove actual path name pls?

N.B: i use react-native-router

thanks in advance for help

Comment: The screenshot doesn't match the code you've shared. I don't see in the screen shot where it's rendering any path values. From what I can tell from the screenshot, the app is on the home page `"/"` and the `Home` component is rendering some `"Home"` text, something rendering some `"test"` text, and a button with `"FRAIS"` text. This all appears to closely match what the `FreshPage` component renders. It's not clear what any issue is here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.